# Reset values of all UITextfield in custom table cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I have many UITextFields in 2 UITabBar and I am trying to create a reset button where the values of all UITextFields become blank so user can restart the whole process. 
I have UITableViewCell class for each cell because the cell are custom and static cells. 
I have Reset Button in my 3rd Tab and would like the values in Tab 2 and Tab 3 to clear. 
I have tried creating instance of CustomTableViewCell and set the value of UITextField to blank but is not working. 
Any help will be highly appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the UITableViewCells have to do with UITabBar but one solution that will surely work is: you listen for notification inside the cells and send the notification when reset button is pressed.

Other solutions depend on your implementation.